# Can't connect to SQL Server on Server 2008 R2 VM; port 1433 is open

Tags: sql-server, sockets, tcp, sql-server-2008-r2, ports

I have a virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2. The host is running Windows 7. I can connect to the SQL server from the VM using SQL Server authentication, but I can't connect from the host using the same method and credentials. I can ping the VM from the host, but I can't telnet to port 1433. On the VM, port 1433 is open through the firewall, TCP/IP is enabled on the SQL instance, and all IP addresses in TCP/IP properties are enabled. I have verified that SQL Server is listening on port 1433. I've been trying to figure this out for two days and I'm about at wit's end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be the IP address I was trying to connect on. The VM would respond to pings, but nothing else was listening there, I take it. Changing the IP address for the VM in my hosts file to the first one listed under the VM's ipconfig fixed it. (I'd taken the IP address I was trying to use from SQL Server Configuration Manager, which got it from ???.) Our network guy figured it out for me, so I can't give more details, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Goto `SQL Server Configuration Manager` from start menu then from the left pane choose `SQL Server Network Configuration` then choose your instance name..
Then from the right pane choose `TCP/IP` .. make sure it's enabled then :
In its `properties` > `IP Addresses` clear any field named `TCP Dynamic Ports` and for any field named `TCP Port` set its value to `1433`

Comment: Also make sure `SQL Server Browser` service is running.

Comment: There are no items under SQL Server Network Configuration. Maybe I'm missing something else? Edit: Browser service is running.

Comment: You should find the instance you installed.. Try installing another instance name maybe you're missing something.